# How can I check if a relative path resolves to outside the closure of an absolute path?

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm, filesystems, relative-path

I am busy with a folder browser widget for web pages. It has a constraint/guideline of a `RootDir`, which is the 'highest' the browser will browse.

So if I set `RootDir` to `C:\Test` and the user types `\` into the address box on my widget, it will browse `C:\Test` as if it were the machine root.

I would like to be sure that the directory the user can access via a relative path resolves to an absolute path that I can find looking under `C:\Test". How can I do this, if I can do it?

Comment: Nothing. I was hoping there was an established manner of doing this so I avoid "not invented here" syndrome and duplicate someone else's effort.

Comment: Something like this: `var isInRootDir = Directory.GetFiles(rootDir, Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(rootDir, userInput)), SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList().Any();` I didn't tried that code, but it can be something to start on.

Comment: I would just resolve the full path and compare prefix... If it doesn't match - reject.